# Naive Bayes, how to get conditional probability of continuous value

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, naive-bayes

I know for nominal value, it is easy to get the conditional probability $\hat{p}(x_i|c)$. But for continuous value, as far as I know, I can assume $\hat{p}(x_i|c)\sim{\mathcal{N}(\mu_{c,i},\sigma^2_{c,i})}$, and I can get $\mu_{c,i}$ and $\sigma^2_{c,i}$ from training data to get the correct $\hat{p}(x_i|c)$.

But not all training data has a normal distribution, How can I know its distribution and perform Naive Bayes Classification?

Comment: I've made some corrections but your should check the subscripts in your mathematics -- it looks odd. Do you mean $\mu_{c,i}$ where you have $\mu_c,_i$?

Comment: @Glen_b, yes,$ \mu_c,_i$

Comment: @AlexanderYau But then your question is quite general, though, no? Given a sample of some continuous distribution, how can you determine the distribution and its parameters.